# Infinispan Implicit Cache Lock Release Fail Forever

Tags: java, caching, transactions, ejb, infinispan

In my application, I have configured Infinispan cache to run on a single node with the following configurations.

```
<local-cache-configuration name="local-txn-cache-template">
   <locking isolation="READ_COMMITTED" acquire-timeout="25000" concurrency-level="1"></locking>
   <transaction mode="NON_XA"
                locking="PESSIMISTIC"
                transaction-manager- 
                         lookup="org.infinispan.transaction.lookup.JBossStandaloneJTAManagerLookup"
                complete-timeout="25000"
                auto-commit="true"
                notifications="true"
                reaper-interval="25000"
                stop-timeout="25000"/>
</local-cache-configuration>
```

Since my application is related to the financial domain it requires following a strict locking mechanism. To achieve this Infinispan Implicit locking has been used as below

```
    protected void txnHelperCacheLock(String tenantCode, AbstractCacheTxnHelper abstractCacheTxnHelper, String lockID, int cashAcntID) {
        String lockValue = lockID + "_" + System.currentTimeMillis();
        logger.info("LN:797", "===== TXNLockCheck request found for cashAcc:" + cashAcntID + " lock id:" + lockValue);
        omsServicesI.remoteLockCashAccountsByCashAcntId(tenantCode, cashAcntID,abstractCacheTxnHelper.getUnqReqId());
        abstractCacheTxnHelper.setRootKey(lockID);
        abstractCacheTxnHelper.setUnqReqId(lockValue);
        cacheAdaptorI.cachePut(tenantCode, abstractCacheTxnHelper.getRootKey(), abstractCacheTxnHelper.getUnqReqId(), CACHE_NAMES.TXN_LOCK_CACHE);
        abstractCacheTxnHelper.setLockAckAt(DateUtils.getCurrentDate());
    }
```

But under high load, if a certain cache key gets locked it will forever, and each subsequent attempt to lock the same key will result in a lock acquisition timeout exception as follow

```
javax.ejb.EJBTransactionRolledbackException: ISPN000299: Unable to acquire lock after 25 seconds for key BP_GRP_ID_26521 and requestor GlobalTx:local:5. Lock is held by GlobalTx:local:2
```

Any suggestion would be highly appreciated.

Comment: unfortunately, it is impossible to help without a reproducer or trace logging. Maybe open a ticket in https://issues.redhat.com/projects/ISPN/issues ?

Comment: Which Infinispan version? How are you starting the transaction, and are you committing/rolling back in a finally block? Your code only shows calls to your own application's classes, not to the Infinispan or JTA API.

Comment: @DanBerindei My application is backed with Java EE and runs on the JBOSS application server. Therefore container manage EJB transaction is created using Transaction annotaion and the container is all responsible for commit and rollback created transaction. My code structure as follows                                                                                  
Transaction
public void processOrder(){
 // validations
 cache1.put(k,v1) // need to acquire lock
 // do some action
}
if any exception found then mark rollback using sessionContext.setRollbackOnly(); inside finally block.

Comment: @pruivo Thanks mate, sure i will.

Comment: @DanBerindei I noticed that when I call cache1.put(k,v1) to acquire the lock, Infinispan itself opens a transaction apart from the EJB transaction. Is this the required behavior?

Comment: @pruivo I have created an issue https://issues.redhat.com/browse/ISPN-13024 in this link attached with JBOSS server log as well. Help is much appreciated since i have stuck with this for weeks now

Comment: is there a reason to have JBossTM timeout == Infinispan's lock timeout? Usually, you want the Infinispan's lock timeout smaller than JBossTM timeout. Also, the logs shows you are invoking `sleep()` in method `com.dfn.oms.newgen.core.tx.logic.cache.OMSCacheTransactionManager#loadTXNBeanFromCache()`. In any case, it seems a concurrency bug in ISPN.

Comment: @pruivo Yes thing is in my application inside a single JBoss transaction there are multiple actions acquiring Implicit lock. To recreate the same scenario i
set JBossTM timeout == Infinispan's lock timeout and place thread sleep(). 
But despite any action, the Infinipan cache lock must release without persisting forever, isn't it?

Comment: @pruivo Much appreciate your cooperation. How can I get a fix for this?

Comment: if you don't want to wait for the next Infinispan 12 / 13 release, you can pick the commit from https://github.com/infinispan/infinispan/pull/9310 and compile Infinispan yourself. You'll need Java 11 & maven 3.6+.

Comment: @pruivo Is bug fix version 12.1.3? When can we have it?

Comment: it didn't make it in time for 12.1.3.Final payload. it should be available in the next micro release. Sorry.

Comment: @pruivo Again thank you for your immediate response and all your support. I've compiled Infinispan source with fix commit and it works without persisting cache lock.
After the change, if a timeout occurs due to lock acquire, I received "javax.ejb.EJBTransactionRolledbackException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Lock already released!" exception on all occasions replacing the previous exception string of "javax.ejb.EJBTransactionRolledbackException: ISPN000299: Unable to acquire lock after 25 seconds for" is this because of overkill action as you mention in your comment?

Comment: yes. it is signalling that the cache.put() failed. I need to replace the exception's message with something more friendly :)